# Where is the flaw in my permutations answer?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm working on the following problem from 1.8 in DeGroot and Schervish's *Probability and Statistics*:

[image]

It seems to me there are $n!$ ways to seat the row overall. Of those, $2(n-1)$ have A and B sitting next to each other. (Just think about placing AB at the start of the row, then sliding them down all the way to the end of the row, and doing the same with BA). So then, the probability $A$ and $B$ are seated next to each other are:

$\frac{2(n-1)}{n!}$

But then, when I looked at the solutions, I see: 
[image]

Where did I go wrong with my logic?

Comment: There are $2(n-1)!$ ways to seat them with A and B adjacent. Think of the adjacent pair AB as single person: you're seating $n-1$ people in any order. The same happens with the BA pair. $\frac{2(n-1)!}{n!}=\frac{2}n$.

Answer (score 12):

You forgot to account for all the possible permutations of the **other** $n-2$ people sitting down.

Thus the right answer is indeed 
$$\frac{2(n-1)}{n!}\cdot (n-2)!=\frac{2}{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways in which $A$ and $B$ can be seated next to each other is $2(n-1)$, which is the numerator you have.  The denominator is the number of ways in which $A$ and $B$ can be seated.  This value is $n(n-1)$ (not $n!$) because the seat for $A$ can be chosen in $n$ ways and the seat for $B$ can be chosen in $n-1$ ways.  The ratio is $2/n$.